# How to add Time column in the sentinel 5p data

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-5p

These codes ([Google earth engine to download each pixel values in CSV format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75029853/google-earth-engine-to-download-each-pixel-values-in-csv-format)) provide me latitude, longitude and CH4 values with system index column. I need a column with time that should give time series values like '2021-04-08','2021-04-09' and so on. How I can add time column in the following codes:

```
var startDate = '2021-04-08';
var endDate = '2021-10-19';

Map.addLayer(region)
Map.centerObject(region, 6)

// Create a date filter to get data from the specified month

var dateFilter = ee.Filter.date(startDate, endDate);

// Get the mean data for the specified month and region

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/OFFL/L3_CH4')
          .select('CH4_column_volume_mixing_ratio_dry_air_bias_corrected')
          .filterBounds(region)
          .filter(dateFilter)

var meanData = dataset.mean().clip(region);

var band_viz = {
  min: 1750,
  max: 1900,
  palette: ['black', 'blue', 'purple', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']
};
Map.addLayer(meanData, band_viz)

// Extract the pixel values, latitude, and longitude

var features = meanData.addBands(ee.Image.pixelLonLat()).sampleRegions({
collection: region,
properties: ['CH4'],
scale: 1113.2 
});

// Export the data to a CSV file

Export.table.toDrive({
collection: features,
fileFormat: "CSV",
folder: "gee",
fileNamePrefix: "mean_tropomi_CH4_data" 
});
```